# C Linux - Not Writing Integers

Tags: c, linux

I don't know why I keep getting troubles to write an integer to a file.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {


  int fd, w;
  int num=80;

  fd=open ("file3.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0777);

  if (fd>0) {

    w=write (fd, &num, sizeof (int));

        if (w==-1) {

          printf ("Writing Error \n");
          return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

  }

  close (fd);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Does anyone know what could it be?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: What's the problem? What does `strerror(errno)` say?

Comment: The file is created with stuff like P\00\00\00...

Comment: Do you expect the decimal representation in the file? You should get the bytes.

Comment: From man 2 write: On success, the number of bytes written is returned (zero indicates nothing was written).  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately. Check errno to find out.

Comment: @SabrinaMadelaine it just so happens that ASCII `P` has the decimal value of 80. Does that give you any hints?

Answer (score 7):

You're writing binary values to the file, not ascii.  If you want ascii in the file, you need to `sprintf` it first to a `char` buffer, then `write` the char buffer.  Or open your file with `fopen` instead of `open` and use `fprintf`.

p.s. you want `close(fd)` inside your `if (fd > 0) {` block.  Also, technically the only error return of `open` is `-1`.  All other values (positive, zero, negative) are success.

Comment: Thank you all... I did the following:

    int fd, w;
    int num=80;
    char buffer[15];

    sprintf (buffer, "%d", num);
    w=write (fd, buffer, strlen (buffer));

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it is working 100% correctly: `P` happens to be decimal 80.

`write()` is outputting bytes of the integer not a decimal representation.

You might want to look at `fopen` and `fprintf` as an easy way to get what it looks like you are expecting.